# Router behind the switch (DMZ)

Tags: router, dmz

I am new to the world of networking and am having a hard time to solve this issue.

I want to access my server from outside by configuring the server IP in DMZ host but it is not giving me access from outside.

I think the problem is the switch because the server is not connected directly to the router so I should configure the switch IP inside DMZ host or what?

Comment: if your router has another port, what if you plug another comp into your router, not on your "switch",  can that comp access your server?

Comment: @Faisal Why are you commenting to me? I haven't replied to your question ...

Comment: @barlop thanks for your reply but actually i don't have extra port on the router and more if i connect the server directly to the router then the LAN users will not be able to access the server locally .

Comment: @DavidPostill I am sorry .

Comment: @Faisal No problem ;)

Comment: @RyanBabchishin , yes i have a switch between the router and server and yes i can ping the server from the router but i think you are right i have some problem in the router , actually the router has no port forwarding option that's why i am using DMZ , i think i have to change the router . thank you bro

Comment: @barlop , Yes i can access the server from the router but the problem is , i can't access the router or the server from different network . there is an WAN IP statically configured on the router and when i tried to type what is my IP in the google the router showing me another Global IP , however i tried both IP's to access the router but i get faild :(

Comment: @Faisal Firstly not all routers support NAT loopback - going from a local computer accessing the public IP and to another local computer. So you should try it from outside.  And Secondly, you will still only @ see the public IP of the router, but with the DMZ it will forward on to the IP of a local computer that won't be seen from outside your router. Go to an online port scanning website like grc.com shields up (ignore the FUD on that site - a closed port is not insecure), but use the scanner, see if it shows port as open or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the switch is just a normal consumer grade switch, then don't worry about it unless it is completely not working.

In the router config, you need to enable the DMZ and have it send all traffic to your server's IP address. Or, you can setup port forwarding and just forward the ports you need to the server instead.

If the DMZ thing really isn't working and everything else seems fine, try port forwarding instead.